# Is it possible to change the color of disabled active mdSwitch of Angular material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using Angular Material [md-switch](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/switch). In documentation it is showing some different color when the switch is enabled. But I need a functionality like changing the color of switch when it is in **Disabled Active**. Please help me in acheving this. Thanks in advance.

```html
<md-switch aria-label="Switch 11" ng-class="{'md-checked':database.somevalue.value['alarm']}" 
            ng-disabled="true"> Alarm
</md-switch>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/WoNdwg)

[image]

CSS

```
md-switch[disabled].activeDisabled .md-container > div
{
  cursor: default;
  background: lightgreen;
}

md-switch[disabled].activeDisabled .md-container > div > div
{
  background: green;
}
```

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-switch ng-class="{activeDisabled: data.cb1}" ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled active switch" ng-model="data.cb1">
    Switch (Disabled, Active)
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-class="{activeDisabled: data.cb2}" ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled active switch" ng-model="data.cb2">
    Switch (Disabled, Active)
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-class="{activeDisabled: data.cb3}" ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled active switch" ng-model="data.cb3">
    Switch (Disabled, Active)
  </md-switch>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
.controller('SwitchDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    cb1: true,
    cb2: false,
    cb3: false
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to change the color for the 4th option alone i.e, Switch (Disabled, Active) of the list?

Comment: Need another help mate, there is a problem in this code. For example, if I have 3 switches. three are disabled(Inactive) intially and after some time one switch is in active(but disable only). At that time I need to change the color of active switch alone. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use watch method for that in angular to keep watch on ng-model variable to define logic inside it.